# load part of page when cash page in server side

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Page contains product details and rate them.
Rating is 5 stars that is works with `ajax`.
I want to cache these pages in server side but how can i cache product details without rating.

```
    <div class='product-container'  >
            <div class='product-container-right'  >
                <h3>product-name</h3><br/>
            <p>some detail about product</p>
            </div>
            <div class='vote-request'>rate this product:</div><br/>
            <div id='productvote-20' class='product-vote' >

                    <input type='checkbox' name='vote' value='1' />

                    <input type='checkbox' name='vote' value='2' />

                    <input type='checkbox' name='vote' value='3' />

                    <input type='checkbox' name='vote' value='4' />

                    <input type='checkbox' name='vote' value='5' />

            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to cache `div class='product-container-right'` in server side.
**how every time page (`div class='product-container-right'`) is loaded from cache read `div id='productvote-20' class='product-vote'` by `javascript( or jquery)`.**

Answer (score 0):

you need to add AJAX request that will run once on document-ready to get rating from PHP page and update the rating

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#productvote-20').load('Rating.php?productId=1');
})
```

And in that PHP file, you need to output this.. but don't cache that page

```
 <input type='checkbox' name='vote' value='1' />

 <input type='checkbox' name='vote' value='2' />

 <input type='checkbox' name='vote' value='3' />

 <input type='checkbox' name='vote' value='4' />

 <input type='checkbox' name='vote' value='5' />
```